# Is there a way to force an Android tablet to use layout-hdpi instead of layout-xlarge?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm not sure if I'm missing something and there's an easy way to do this. Can I just delete my layout-xlarge folder and it will automatically use the layout-hdpi?

Comment: Why do you even *have* `res/layout-hdpi/`? IMHO, layout resources should not vary by screen density.

Comment: We had different design layouts for 10" tablet and for phone. Now with 7" tablets, the 10" layout doesn't look right.

Comment: Then use `res/layout/`, `res/layout-large/`, and `res/layout-xlarge/`. The latter two will be for ~7" and ~10" tablets, respectively.

Comment: *bump* i actually need a way to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use one folder called 'layout'.  CommonsWare is totally right.  You should be using relative positioning.  Don't design for one particular screen.

Comment: The designers decided to go with a totally different layout for tablets, it's not to do with positioning.